# Timing a function to run after an image element has changed its src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm changing the src attribute from some images. After the new images have been loaded, I want to run a function called wheelBuilder.rebuildColors()

```
$images.each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-original-front-src"));
});
wheelBuilder.rebuildColors();
```

This code works fine on some browsers (chrome, safari, ie), but not on Mozilla firefox.

Is there a way for the to set it to run the function after all the images have loaded?

thanks

Comment: I guess you could use the onload event of the image tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onload

Comment: You want to call that function when the images are loaded? Doesn't really look like it is doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You must set the function before changing the src

```
var total = $images.length,loaded=0;
function testRebuild() {
  if (loaded==total) wheelBuilder.rebuildColors();
}
$images.each(function() {
  this.onload=function() {
    loaded++; testRebuild();
  }
  this.onerror=function() {
    $(this).hide();
    loaded++; testRebuild();
  }
  $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-original-front-src"));
});
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that some of these images don't exist and are being hidden by an on error handler, so the loaded variable will never reach the total variable